# how to get list of rows shown in ng-grid in controller?

Tags: angularjs, search, ng-grid

i have ng-grid with a search option. I need to get the list of all rows which shown during search in the controller.
I know about the selected list option. But i need the rows without selection.

Comment: All rows found (with pagination) or all rows currently shown (rendered)? With server sided filtering or client sided filtering? Any chance you can give a link to a Plunker or Fiddle?

Comment: all rows shown currently after rendering. client side filtering is used.